# EL not evaluated in the 'id' field

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Currently I am using a rich:dataTable to loop through records.  I simply output the text like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{property.variableName}" />
```

This displays the data properly in the table.  Now I want to add IDs to test my stuff.  I tried adding the same property as the ID like this:

```
<h:outputText id="#{property.variableName}" value="#{property.variableName}" />
```

The result is an empty ID error.  I prepended it with "id_" and all that gets returned to the DOM is "id_"  (no property variableName) added to it.

Am I losing my mind?  I feel as if this should work as I've done it in the past.

Comment: I managed to work around my issue by using the "alt" parameter instead of "id".  For some reason it evaluates there.  If anyone else is reading this and knows why I would get such behavior please feel free to educate me :)

Comment: What is the purpose of assigning an `id` a dynamic value? It is not available in your use-case because an `id` associated with any JSF component is evaluated during view build time. Thus, any EL being evaluated for an `id` has to be available during view build time (using `<c:forEach>`, for example) which might not be available at view build time in your case (as you said you were iterating over a RichFaces' data table).